# EBook reader with built in dictionary?

Tags: ebook

While reading literature text on my computer, I usually come across many words which I don't understand. It's pain to constantly switch from for eg. Adobe Reader to Google Dictionary.

So, I am looking for an ebook reader with built in dictionary. The reader should support PDF format (unlike Kindle for PC) which is the main format I use.

Comment: (Not posted as an answer because I don't know if it will work.) The Nook supports PDF, and so long as said PDF is text and not images of text (e.g. a scanned book on which no OCR was done), it's capable of looking up individual words in its dictionary. I imagine the PC/Mac/Android/iPhone Nook Reader apps also have this feature, but I've not heavily used those so I can't say for certain, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Do try [WordWeb](http://www.wordweb.info/). Incase you haven't heard about it, its simply a dictionary application for Windows (and iOS), not an e-book reader. Install it; when you come across any text on your computer which you don't understand, select the text and press Ctrl + Alt + W. (This shortcut key is merely the default can be modified in the HotKey section of WordWeb.)